# Remove object property and still being able to loop through that object

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to emulate setInterval:

```
var Animator=new (function(){
var jobs={
    interval:{}
}

var self=this;
var assignedIntervalNum=0;

this.setInterval=function(func,interval){
    jobs.interval[assignedIntervalNum]={
        func:func,
        latest:Date.now()-interval,
        interval:interval
    };
    assignedIntervalNum++;
    return assignedIntervalNum-1;
}

this.clearInterval=function(key){
    delete jobs.interval[key];
}

var requestNextFrame=function(){
    var now=Date.now();
    for (var key in jobs.interval){
        if (jobs.interval[key].latest + jobs.interval[key].interval < now){
            jobs.interval[key].func();
            jobs.interval[key].latest=now;
        }
    }

    setTimeout(function(){requestNextFrame();},1);
}
requestNextFrame();
})();
```

But I keep getting an error stating that jobs.interval[key] is undefined. So i guess delete doesn't exactly remove that property but simply assign it to `undefined` !?

What are my options for a key/value storage that support removal of pairs and looping through each of them?

**EDIT**

My bad!

there was a call to clearInterval in the function func(), so the line that was causing the error was jobs.interval[key].latest=now; Just after it's deletion.

So yeah, javascript objects are still good options for a key/value storage that support removal of pairs and looping through each of them

Comment: Yes, it does remove that property, but there's a default value of `undefined` returned when accessing properties that don't exist.

Comment: `delete` does remove properties from objects. While acessing an undefined property gives `undefined` by default, you can check if an object actually has a property by using the `hasOwnProperty` method or the `in` operator (the difference is that `in` also checks the prototype chain for the property...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the question, this was a mistake!

Answer (score 0):

"delete" doesn't delete the object from the array, it sets the object as undefined, so that's why you are getting that error.

If you want to delete an object from an array which has the index i, you can use:

```
array.splice(i, 1);
```

where 1 is the number of elements you want to delete starting at the position i.

If you want to delete one element from the array "array" by the key, you can use:

```
for (var i=0; i<array.length; i++){
    if (array[i]==key){
        array.splice(i, 1);
        break;
    }
}
```